# How to use VUEX GETTERS in script

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm using VUEX GETTERS for some variables. I can use them in the html part but I cannot edit or change them in the script->data part.

ERROR:[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "ReferenceError: Positions is not defined"

```
<script>
import {mapGetters} from 'vuex'
export default {
        data: () => ({
            dialog: false,
            TotalEntitiy:Positions[0] // GIVES ERROR
        }),       
        computed:{
            ...mapGetters({
                PageTitle:  'GETTER_CURRENT_PAGE',
                headers:   'GETTER_HEADERS',
                Positions: 'GETTER_POSITIONS',
                items:'GETTER_ITEMS'
            }),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `TotalEntity` a new computed property instead of part of the component's data, since it has to be reactive based on the value from the store:

```
data: () => ({
    dialog: false
}),       
computed:{
    ...mapGetters({
        PageTitle:  'GETTER_CURRENT_PAGE',
        headers:   'GETTER_HEADERS',
        Positions: 'GETTER_POSITIONS',
        items:'GETTER_ITEMS'
    }),
    TotalEntity() {
        return this.Positions[0];
    }
}
```

Update: to circumvent potential issues that `this.Positions` might be `null` or `undefined`, you can use the [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
return this.Positions?.[0];
```

You can also use [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to fallback to a default value:

```
return this.Positions?.[0] ?? YOUR_FALLBACK_VALUE;
```

Comment: I think return this.Positions &&  return this.Positions[0] would be better as this.Positions can be undefined at some point

Comment: @VirajSingh Thanks: updated my answer to include handling of `null` or `undefined` values